# How to get text from specific child(button) when there are many

Tags: unity-game-engine, children

I have 6 buttons. Each has a different text on it. Pushing any button calls the one same method which changes the text and changes button positions between them. I can't figure out how to get the text from a specific button when it pushed. I can only return either random button text or all of them. Somewhat like this:

```
    public void ReadFromButton()
{
    Button button;
    button = GetComponent<Button>();
    var koba = button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    Debug.Log(koba);



}
```

So I need any advice. Thanks.

[buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aHsa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `int` to your button click function like `ReadFromButton(int i)` and then in unity give your buttons numbers in onclickevent, according to your `public Text[] buttontexts`

Like:

```
public Text[] buttontexts;  
public void ReadFromButton(int i)
{
    var koba = buttontexts[i].text;
    Debug.Log(koba);
}
```

But i believe there is more ways to do that.